# ImageMagik on CentOS not working with PNG files

Tags: centos, imagemagick, png, libpng

I am having trouble with ImageMagik on CentOS.
The error is:

> Error: identify: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @
>   error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.

```
convert -list configure

Path: /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.5.4/config/configure.xml

Name          Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CC            gcc -std=gnu99
CFLAGS        -fopenmp -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -W -pthread
CONFIGURE     ./configure  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-modules' '--with-perl' '--with-x' '--with-threads' '--with-magick_plus_plus' '--with-gslib' '--with-wmf' '--with-lcms' '--with-rsvg' '--with-xml' '--with-perl-options=INSTALLDIRS=vendor  CC='\''gcc -L/builddir/build/BUILD/ImageMagick-6.5.4-7/magick/.libs'\'' LDDLFLAGS='\''-shared -L/builddir/build/BUILD/ImageMagick-6.5.4-7/magick/.libs'\''' '--without-dps' '--without-included-ltdl' '--with-ltdl-include=/usr/include' '--with-ltdl-lib=/usr/lib64' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic'
COPYRIGHT     Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS      -I/usr/include/ImageMagick
CXX           g++
CXXFLAGS      -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -W -pthread
DEFS          -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES     bzlib fontconfig freetype gs jpeg jng jp2 lcms openexr png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --disable-deprecated --with-quantum-depth=16 --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no --with-dps=no --with-fontpath=
EXEC-PREFIX   /usr
HOST          x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
LDFLAGS       -L/usr/lib64 -lfreetype
LIB_VERSION   0x654
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 6,5,4,7
LIBS          -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl
NAME          ImageMagick
PCFLAGS       -fopenmp
PREFIX        /usr
QuantumDepth  16
RELEASE_DATE  2014-02-10
VERSION       6.5.4
WEBSITE       http://www.imagemagick.org
```

I can see "PNG" in the list of DELEGATES but there doesn't seem to be anything in the LIBS section (see above).

I have tried installing libpng, which is already installed and I've have re-installed ImageMagik from source but it still isn't working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`configure` attempts to configure with every available image delegate, so when you're building from source, you'll need to have the `libpng-devel` package installed. If for some reason it didn't detect it, you may want to try forcing it with `--with-png=yes` in your options to `configure` to get some feedback.

See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php

Comment: This solved the problem, I didn't have the devel version of libpng installed.